# Storing a parameter in an array in a URL as a variable in PHP

Tags: php, get

Here is the URL:

```
https://all.burgbuilderdev.com/results-page/?address%5B0%5D=Milwaukee%2C%20WI%2053207&post%5B0%5D=project&distance=30&units=imperial&per_page=5&lat=42.971207&lng=-87.904057&form=2&action=fs
```

I realize it is in an array but I can't figure out how to target it and store it as a variable. I'm certain this is dumb (I'm a beginner with PHP) but I've tried things like:

```
$address = $_GET['address'];

and

$address = $_GET ['address%5B0%5D'];

and

$address = $_GET['address[0]'];
```

to no avail.. Thanks for stopping by!

Comment: Have a look at the data. `var_dump($_GET);` to see how it's actually represented in the array and what the key name is

Comment: **In PHP**, instead of passing "address[0]", you can pass "address[]". For example, to pass 3 elements: `?address[]=one&address[]=two&address[]=three`. Then, `$_GET['address']` will be an array with elements `one`, `two` and `three` (order _may not be_ guaranteed). Although I can't remember from the top of my head if, in this case, [] should be encoded in the url or not (I _strongly_ believe that no).

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
$url = 'https://all.burgbuilderdev.com/results-page/?address%5B0%5D=Milwaukee%2C%20WI%2053207&post%5B0%5D=project&distance=30&units=imperial&per_page=5&lat=42.971207&lng=-87.904057&form=2&action=fs';
```

We can parse it like PHP automatically does:

```
$parsed = parse_url($url);

parse_str($parsed['query'], $parsedQuery);

var_dump(
    $parsed,
    $parsedQuery,
    $parsedQuery['address'][0]   // <<< Here is like $_GET
);
```

Renders (partial):

```
array(9) {
  ["address"]=>                       // <<< address key
  array(1) {                          // <<< Address is array w/one item
    [0]=>                             // <<< First item, zero index
    string(19) "Milwaukee, WI 53207"  // <<< Here
  }
  ["post"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "project"
  }
  ["distance"]=>
  string(2) "30"
...
```

https://3v4l.org/S7X7L

So in other words, PHP automatically does the above for `GET`, so it would be:

```
$_GET['address'][0]
```